# ask ubuntu forum and a mailing list

Tags: discussion

Can people post to this forum from a mailing list?

For example, would it be possible to use the forum software here in such a way that you never needed to use a web browser? Could you do it all by e-mail - sending posts to the forum by e-mail and receving replies from the forum by e-mail too?

I am not asking to start sending a mailing list content to this forum. I just want to know if it is capable of handling it.

By the way, I heard that tags to post comments don't really help things. Is that right? They aren't meant to improve search results, somebody said to me... But I suppose you might be able to filter searches by tag, so I don't know.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question about tags and comments seems unrelated to this. If it is a different question, you should [ask it separately](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask) (here on meta, not on the main site). If it's not a different question, then you should edit your question here for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. The best you can do is subscribe to a tag to receive the questions via email or subscribe to the email newsletter.

- [Is it possible to receive and post reply to questions via email](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54451/is-it-possible-to-receive-and-post-reply-to-questions-via-email)

If you think about how the system works doing AU via email wouldn't work, the entire point of the system is to not do post-reply-over-and-over, questions and answers are just edited as information about the problem is discovered.

As far as tags go, they should be used to describe the question you're asking. By default it seems that google at least picks up the first tag and displays it in the search results.

Comment: I'd like to add that [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) has this feature, and while it's useful, it also results in a lot of spam, both from people's hijacked email accounts and (less frequently, but still somewhat frequently) from emails with [spoofed headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing).

Comment: They have been getting better at removing older comments, quite often I respond to a bug post on the road via email, and it autoremoves the `------ Original Message ------` stuff